# How can I layout a line with an arrow in a flexible grid?

Tags: wpf, layout, line

My WPF window contains a Grid that stretches to the entire window width and layouts some controls along the way. Inmidst of these controls, there should be displayed some lines with arrows on one end, that visualise some kind of flow. The lines span across multiple grid columns or rows and have some margin to each sides, to keep them away from the other controls. Multiple lines have certain connection points where they must touch. For now, I only need horizontal and vertical lines.

I've tried with the Line control, but that seems to require X and Y coordinates for both ends, in pixels. That's not easy because the line may stretch as the user changes the window size.

Next was the Path control, but I don't know how to add arrow ends there. The Path data was "M0,0 L1,0" with Stretch="Fill", so if I draw an arrow in the path, it would stretch as well, which I shouldn't do.

What alternatives are there to stretch a line but not the arrow on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roll your own control

```
public sealed class Arrow : FrameworkElement
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
       var width = ActualWidth;
       var height = ActualHeight;
       drawingContext.Draw...; // Draw you arrow line here
       drawingContext.Draw...; // Draw you arrow head here 
    }
}
```

Of course, you can add all sorts of dependency properties to it in order to control how your arrow is drawn.

Comment: After some more searching, it seems I was mistaken by graphic editor applications that one could easily add arrow heads to lines in WPF, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Here's a good solution that implements a custom control: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrochon/archive/2011/01/10/custom-line-caps-in-wpf.aspx I've added a sub class that manages arrow length and width easier. After all this declarative markup in XAML, I forgot that you could also do paint-on-demand just like in Windows Forms...